# Como juntar três séries temporais em uma só?

Tags: r, data.frame, séries-temporais

Estou tentando juntar três séries de tempo em uma só, porém estou tendo vários problemas.

Usei a junção `c` do R, mas não me é útil pois como se trata de séries mensais, esse comando mistura as observações das três séries e fica uma bagunça.

Utilizei o pacote [plyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html) e o [magrittr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/index.html) pra criar um `data.frame` contendo as três séries anteriores como colunas, mas com o primeiro pacote, a função `join_all` me retornou um `data.frame` vazio, e com o segundo o R diz que os parâmetros das séries são inválidos (ps.: mas elas contêm a mesma dimensão).

Abaixo eu deixo os comandos que eu usei pra uma melhor compreensão:

```
cimento <- read.table(file='cimento.csv', sep=';', header=T)

Carbono01 <- (300 + (0.2*cimento))
Carbono02 <- (300 + (0.2*(cimento^2/2)))
Carbono03 <- (300 + (0.2*cimento) + (cimento^2/4000))

Carbono01 <- as.data.frame(Carbono01)
Carbono02 <- as.data.frame(Carbono02)
Carbono03 <- as.data.frame(Carbono03)

install.packages("plyr")
library(plyr) 
carbono <- join_all(list(Carbono01, Carbono02,Carbono03)) 
carbono
rm(carbono)

install.packages("magrittr")
library(magrittr)
carbono <- Carbono01%>%merge(Carbono02)%>%merge(Carbono03)
carbono
```

Edit: `str(cimento)`

```
Time-Series [1:242] from 1996 to 2016: 3391 3436 3630 3677 3460 3308 3645 3707 3677 3629 ...
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: atualiza a pergunta com o resultado de `str(cimento)`

Comment: Feito...........

Comment: Tente `Carbono01 <- data.frame(ID = seq_along(Carbono01), Carbono01)` e o mesmo para os outros. Sem uma coluna comum (neste caso `ID`) como é que o `join_all` pode juntar os df's? E ainda, para séries temporais, veja os pacotes `zoo` ou `xts`.

Comment: Boa tarde, amigo! Estive tentando fazer o que você me recomendou, mas o R só me retorna isso como resposta: `Error in `[<-.ts`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(1150188.1, 1180909.6, 1317990,  : 
  only replacement of elements is allowed` Não entendo o que está acontecendo.

Answer (score 2):

Eu não sei como é exatamente a sua série que está no arquivo `cimento.csv`. O ideal seria você fornecer uma série temporal exatamente como é a sua. Entretanto creio que o problema para juntar séries temporais pode ser resolvido de forma transparente utilizando o pacote `xts`. Veja um exemplo:

```
library(xts)
serie1 <-as.xts(ts(c(1:12),star=c(2014,1),freq=12))
serie2 <-as.xts(ts(c(13:24),star=c(2015,1),freq=12))
serie3 <- c(serie1, serie2))
```

A seguir cada série como ficou:

```
> serie1
         [,1]
jan 2014    1
fev 2014    2
mar 2014    3
abr 2014    4
mai 2014    5
jun 2014    6
jul 2014    7
ago 2014    8
set 2014    9
out 2014   10
nov 2014   11
dez 2014   12

> serie2
         [,1]
jan 2015   13
fev 2015   14
mar 2015   15
abr 2015   16
mai 2015   17
jun 2015   18
jul 2015   19
ago 2015   20
set 2015   21
out 2015   22
nov 2015   23
dez 2015   24

> serie3
         [,1]
jan 2014    1
fev 2014    2
mar 2014    3
abr 2014    4
mai 2014    5
jun 2014    6
jul 2014    7
ago 2014    8
set 2014    9
out 2014   10
nov 2014   11
dez 2014   12
jan 2015   13
fev 2015   14
mar 2015   15
abr 2015   16
mai 2015   17
jun 2015   18
jul 2015   19
ago 2015   20
set 2015   21
out 2015   22
nov 2015   23
dez 2015   24
```

o interessante é que o método `c()` quando se trata de objetos `xts` já faz todo o trabalho sujo para você.

Comment: Olá, Flávio! Resolveu, mas não ficou separado por colunas, como era minha intenção. Mas muito obrigado, pois ao menos juntou tudo num mesmo objeto, algo que não conseguia de jeito nenhum.

Comment: @LeonardoVinícius caso estiver satisfeito com a resposta marque como a escolha (usando o tick) ;-)